# how to extract pattern from pdf and save to text file

Tags: pdf

How can I extract some pattern contained in PDF file to text file using shell?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pattern'? You need to explain your requirements in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

PDF is a formatted data and you couldn't access its content in shell but
if you install `poppler-utils` ,then you could `convert` it to text and search for your pattern with `grep`

```
pdftotext my.pdf - | grep 'your_pattern' > example.txt
```

so you have your pattern in `example.txt` file .